# Filter search on the frontend

Tags: reactjs, algolia

My site supports 7 different languages. For example, if the users are on the en site, I only want to show en results.

I built the site with React + Sanity (CMS) and need to sync all the documents with Algolia. I plan to put all the documents into one index and filter them by lang in the frontend. These documents have a `lang` attribute which I can use to filter.

```
[
{id: 1, title: "Hello", lang: "en"},
{id: 2, title: "Bonjour", lang: "fr"}
{id: 3, title: "こんにちは", lang: "ja"}
...
]
```

One index for each lang would be much complicated so I keep it simple.

Anyone could show me how to filter those documents in the frontend.

```
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";
import {
    InstantSearch,
    SearchBox,
    InfiniteHits,
    InstantSearchSSRProvider,
} from "react-instantsearch-hooks-web";

export function SearchPage() {

 // I already have the user lang here
const lang = getUserLang()

// How could I filter the search results to include only documents with the correct lang
 
  return (
           <InstantSearch
                searchClient={searchClient}
                indexName={searchIndex}
                insights
            >
                <SearchBox autoFocus={true} placeholder="Search"/>
                <RefinementList attribute="facetingType" />
                    
                <Stats />
                 <InfiniteHits hitComponent={Hit}/>
            </InstantSearch>
   )
}
```

I think I should somehow use the filter API but couldn't figure out how it works with the `react-instantsearch-hooks-web`
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/?client=javascript